# Principles in experiment design for functional data analysis

Tags: references, experiment-design, functional-data-analysis

The goal or objective of "standard"$^†$ experiment design is to design a data collection scheme (for a finite budget) such that linear models$^†$ can be applied and inference results can be guaranteed to be optimal (e.g., variance, power, ...) or have desirable properties (e.g., randomization helps smooth out effects of latent variables).

How do ideas from standard experiment design translate to functional data? What principles should one consider or bear in mind when designing experiments for functional data analysis (FDA)?

For an example, a question one might ask in designing an experiment for FDA is: should measurements be taken at different time steps or all the same? i.e., $x_1(t)$ measured at $t\in\{1,3,5,7,9\}$, and measure $x_2(t)$ at $t\in\{2,4,6,8,10\}$, or $x_1(t), x_2(t)$ both measured at $t\in\{2,4,6,8,10\}$?

References will be accepted in the absence of answers.

† "Standard" and "linear models" in the sense that this is what's typically taught in an introductory course to design of experiments

Comment: Some links which might help: https://testscience.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/formidable/13/Donnelly_DATAWorks-2019.pdf, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11947-020-02449-2